# how to wrap (Vivado) CLI in the windows shell using python subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen, vivado

**Some background:**
Vivado has a CLI that can be called from a windows cmd prompt using

`C:/path_to_vivado/bin/vivado -mode tcl`.

It silently calls several .bat files and set several environment variables until this:
[CLI Vivado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAgKK.png)

So basically at this point you have a tcl interpreter that offers vivado objects, commands, interfaces etc.

(e.g. `lindex [get_parts] 0`  [produce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHCsY.png))

**Goal**: What I want is to wrap it using python. I had already something working but I want something more that I do not know how to implement.

What i would like to have is something like this

Code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT
shl_cmd = r"C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/bin/vivado -mode tcl"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shl_cmd, shell=True ,stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE,  stderr = STDOUT)

tcl_cmd =b'lindex [get_parts] 0\n'
proc.stdin.write(tcl_cmd)
proc.stdin.flush()

#I know this "read all" is blocking but for now it is fine
while(1):                
        out = p.read(1)
        print(out.decode(),end='')
```

Desired Output (that is basically what it is shown in the prompt if I type the command by hand into it instead of using python):

```
****** Vivado v2018.3 (64-bit)
  **** SW Build 2405991 on Thu Dec  6 23:38:27 MST 2018
  **** IP Build 2404404 on Fri Dec  7 01:43:56 MST 2018
    ** Copyright 1986-2018 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Vivado% lindex [get_parts] 0
xc7vx485tffg1157-1
Vivado%
```

But what I have is nothing (stdout is empty and program blocks).

Anyway, if in the previous code tcl_cmd is `tcl_cmd =b'puts [lindex [get_parts] 0]\n'`
I have the output:

```
****** Vivado v2019.1 (64-bit)
  **** SW Build 2552052 on Fri May 24 14:49:42 MDT 2019
  **** IP Build 2548770 on Fri May 24 18:01:18 MDT 2019
    ** Copyright 1986-2019 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

xc7vx485tffg1157-1
```

Note: probably the header is not flushed to the std output until something else it is, so this is why it is not shown before a *puts* instruction.
where I am listening with python, I can read just the stuff that I explicity send using puts, but I do not know why.

**Some Experiments More:**

*Experiment 1:*

```
C:\Users\Corrado>vivado -mode tcl > filelog.txt
lindex [get_parts] 0
puts hello_world
exit
```

And filelog.txt content is:

```
****** Vivado v2018.3 (64-bit)
  **** SW Build 2405991 on Thu Dec  6 23:38:27 MST 2018
  **** IP Build 2404404 on Fri Dec  7 01:43:56 MST 2018
    ** Copyright 1986-2018 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Vivado% xc7vx485tffg1157-1
Vivado% hello_world
Vivado% exit
INFO: [Common 17-206] Exiting Vivado at Tue Nov  5 17:49:52 2019...
```

But for code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(r"C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/bin/vivado -mode tcl > filelog.txt",shell=True ,stdin = PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT )
proc.stdin.write(b'lindex [get_parts] 0\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.write(b'puts hello\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.write(b'exit\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
```

logfile.txt is:

```
****** Vivado v2019.1 (64-bit)
  **** SW Build 2552052 on Fri May 24 14:49:42 MDT 2019
  **** IP Build 2548770 on Fri May 24 18:01:18 MDT 2019
    ** Copyright 1986-2019 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

hello
exit
INFO: [Common 17-206] Exiting Vivado at Tue Nov  5 17:54:32 2019...
```

Note that exit is shown probably because it is not a tcl command and by default unkown command are managed by the application sending them to the shell (I guess I am not really sure of that)

**So it seems like the call from the shell and using subprocess produce different behaviours even if i expect they would be the same.**

I tried to use pexpect too but without success and almost with same results.

I do not care so much about showing the `Vivado%` prompt (even if it would be nice) but I would like to have an exact copy of the content printed in the terminal when i am using the CLI from there even when i'm using the CLI from python. (For example to print it into an internal GUI)

Sorry if I have been a bit verbose but I wanted to be clearer I can.

Comment: Please post the answer if you figured it out

Comment: unfortunately i didn't

Answer (score 0):

in both cases (cmd prompt and python) vivado.log and vivado.jou files are created.

It is usually created in same folder as
*C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/bin/*

you can specify the location of the file explicitly too

```
cmd = "C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/bin/vivado -mode tcl -log C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/bin/vivado.log -journal C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2019.1/bin/vivado.jou"

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd ,shell=True ,stdin = PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT )
```

you could use a generator to read vivado.log file as it updates